# Multiple URL Rewrite Rules (Pretify)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two types of urls:

`http://mydomain.com/npguar/en/products.php`
`http://mydomain.com/npguar/en/1/product_specification.php`

Earlier I was using this `.htaccess` for URL Rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*) $2?language=$1 [L]
```

Then later I modified it to this but it doesnt seems to work

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 ^(product_specification\.php)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{1,2})(.*) $3?language=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|product_specification\.php)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*) $2?language=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how the original rule worked. Start with an URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/npguar/en/index.php?maybe=a-query
```

Take the filesystem path only:

```
npguar/en/index.php
```

Remove the prefix which was used to get to the `.htaccess`:

```
en/index.php
```

Match this against the regex `^([a-z]{2})/(.*)`. It matches, so processing continues. There were subpatterns in the regex, which matched parts of the URL like this:

```
(en)/(index.php)
```

This match defines the backreferences `$1 = en` and `$2 = index.php`.

Now check the corresponding `RewriteCond`. The first argument there is `$1`, which expands to the string `en`. The second argument is `!`, and a regex which doesn't match that string, so the condition is true.

Since the condition is true, go back to the `RewriteRule` and construct the replacement string `$2?language=$1`:

```
index.php?language=en
```

This is an internal redirect, so put the bits of the orignal URL back together. Since there is a query here and the `[QSA]` flag wasn't specified, the original query (`maybe=a-query`) is replaced.

```
http://mydomain.com/npguar/index.php?language=en
```

This URL is handed back to Apache for processing from the beginning. The rewriting rules are checked again (the `[L]` flag doesn't prevent this), but they don't match, and the page is served.

---

The problem with this rule is the `$1` in `RewriteCond`. It should be `$2`. Then the `RewriteCond` would be false in the example above, but true in `en/products.php`.

This works fine though, because the `RewriteCond` is just more lax than you intended.

The new rule doesn't work, because the regex breaks up an URL like this (note where the second `/` goes):

```
(en)/(1)(/product_specification.php)
```

So `$1 = en`, `$2 = 1`, `$3 = /product_specification.php`. Then it compares `$1` to `^product_specification.php`, it doesn't match, and the condition is false.

Instead, the new rule should be:

```
RewriteCond $3 ^product_specification\.php$
            ^^                            ^
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{1,2})/(.*) $3?language=$1&id=$2 [L]
                                    ^
```

(I also added a `$` on the end so that `.../product_specification.phpfoo` isn't matched.)

The same rule can be simply:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([0-9]{1,2})/(product_specification\.php)$ $3?language=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, its working, but can you explain what actually was wrong with my query?